# The Process lsass.exe consume to much network resource in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, process, windows-server-2012, lan, windows-server-2016

To since 2 week, the network has a problem, we detected that the server consume all upload bandwidth.

we verify in the tasks administrator and we find a process called Isass.exe  consuming all upload bandwidth.

I show the images.

[image: WAN Network.png]

[image: Isass.exe Process.png]

Could help us to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for ServerFault than StackOverflow, but I'm pretty sure you'll get downvoted into oblivion if this question is migrated. 

Please do some minimum research (ie. google "troubleshoot lsass windows" at the very least)

Comment: At a closer look, unless that box is authenticating a lot of users using client certificates or smart cards, I'd say your box is properly pwned, time to disconnect and reinstall